# Magento 2.3.4 [SOLVED] can't delete crontab created in development mode

Tags: magento2, crontab, magento-cron, cronjobs

When we created the store in development mode, a conjob was created.

On moving to the definitive domain, we noticed errors in the cron tasks and did an install: cron again

But now I have two cronjobs and I can't erase the old "ff16f1079b ............. 1e87e48139360e1"

When I run the crontab -l query this is what it shows:

```
# crontab -l
MAILTO=""
#       35      3       *       *       *       /bin/sh /usr/local/src/mysql_backup.sh
40      10      *       *       6       /bin/sh /root/modsecurity.sh
#~ MAGENTO START ff16f1079b.............1e87e48139360e1
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/update/cron.php >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END ff16f1079b.............1e87e48139360e1
#~ MAGENTO START 97f2843.............d47eaae
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/update/cron.php >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END 97f2843.............d47eaae
```

the /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/ directory no exists (it was the development directory)

the /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/ directory is correct

I have run cron: remove but it does not delete the old cron

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/httpdocs/bin/magento cron:remove
Magento cron tasks have been removed
crontab -l
MAILTO=""
#       35      3       *       *       *       /bin/sh /usr/local/src/mysql_backup.sh
40      10      *       *       6       /bin/sh /root/modsecurity.sh
#~ MAGENTO START ff16f1079b.............1e87e48139360e1
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/update/cron.php >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END ff16f1079b.............1e87e48139360e1
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to **solve** it was recovering a backup in the folder

/var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/

running afterwards the cron /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/bin/magento cron:remove

and removing again all archives and folders to /var/www/vhosts/domain.es/domain.com/